# Simple CakePHP Portfolio

Tags: php, cakephp

I am building a very simple website ( http://driz.co.uk/beta/ ) using CakePHP to show a portfolio of my work as well a few pages such as about me and contact. I was thinking of just creating each item for my portfolio as a page inside the `/views/pages/` folder but seen as I'm wanting to learn a bit about CakePHP I thought it would be probably better to use a database and store each item in a simple table.

What I need to do is have a simple page like `/portfolio/` which lists all my work to date and then links to each item I have so for example `/portfolio/my-awesome-work/`

I also need to list the items in the sidebar as shown in the link.

For each portfolio item I will need a title, a body (which will store the content and images for each item) and also the client information. I don't need any image upload capabilities as I will be just adding the HTML for it in the database table.

If anyone can help it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Basically others thoughts on this / best practices etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you aren't  asking for a full solution (frowned upon on SO)

First follow the blog tutorial : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog

This is a great place to start as it walks you through all the basics.

As for your particular problem. Creating a `portfolios` table with all the fields you mentioned and baking the code (you'll know what that means when you follow the tutorial) as a starting point will get you half way there.

You could also add in an admin area to manage your system. This would mean you'd need to create a `users` table and add the Auth component